# Class AB linear amplifier design

Tags: analog, linear-regulator, class-ab

I am trying to design a class AB linear amplifier. The required peak current is 450mA. I am just using an ideal biasing at this stage. The schematic is as follows:

[image]

Here are the resulting waveforms.

[image]

The results show that the pmos/nmos can be turned off for half of the cycle. And the problem of zero-crossing is not serious. However, the negative half cycle of the output is cutoff. And the lowest current that can be delivered is only -180mA. So how can I revise the circuit to deliver at least -450mA at the negative half output cycle? Thanks.

Comment: Slight differences between the N channel and P channel devices will cause the theoretical midpoint voltage on the drains to be offset. Should you need this to be kept constant and exactly mid-point, then you need to introduce a regime of negative feedback or tweak the MOSFET characteristics. Negative feedback is the likely answer though.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. Could you please explain more what do you mean by "tweak the MOSFET characteristics"? How can I tweak the MOSFET characteristics in order to make the linear amplifier being able to deliver -420mA output current at the negative cycle?

Comment: I'm no expert on MOSFET design but maybe alter the widths to be more similar or more dissimilar? The basic aim is to get the quiescent voltage mid point to 3 volts DC (no signal).

Comment: Has your plot allowed C76 to charge fully? You should look at currents only after about five time constants 5(6 * 10u).

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. In fact, I have already tried to increase the width of the pmos. In my understanding, this could increase the quiescent voltage via two effects. First, this can reduce the overhead required by pmos. Second, as the width is increased, the output impedance of the pmos reduces. However, although the results show that output quiescent voltage does increase, the LA still cannot deliver -420mA at the negative cycle.

Comment: I'm out of ideas on this - it's a CMOS output and not a standard class AB output so hopefully, someone will come along with their recommendations.

Comment: @Andyaka No problem. Great thanks.

Comment: I might be naive, but... at its peak the input signal is 3V+2.5V = 5.5V. If you add 2.5V of V917...

Comment: @SredniVashtar The voltage supply of 6V is given by the specification. But I can't change it. But thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks. 5(6 * 10u) = 300us. Given the input frequency is 120MHz, the circuit simulator does not have enough memory to run 300us. Also the output current waveforms show that the LA can deliver 420mA at the positive. So I suppose the problem is not the major problem.

Comment: At 120MHz you don't need a 10uF coupling capacitor. Try 10nF.

Comment: Why do you have different widths for NMOS and PMOS? I  got +-450mA in LTspice with width = 4.7m. With C76 = 10n the required settling time was 500ns.

Comment: @BruceAbbot Thanks. I now changed the capacitor to 10n. The output current can now varying from about -420mA to 420mA. But the output voltage got cutoff (saturation). That means the gain is too large. If I reduce the gain by reducing the width of the pmos and nmos, the output current is reduced as well. So is there any method to obtain a sinusoidal output voltage (no saturation) without having the output current being reduced. Thanks.

Comment: When Drain voltage goes below Gate voltage the FET changes to its 'linear' region where it acts like a fixed resistor, and the output voltage 'saturates'. So you need to reduce the Gate threshold. Try L = 0.01u, bias voltages = 2.9V, and peak input voltage = 0.21V.

Comment: @BruceAbbott By reducing the input AC voltage to 0.21V, I can get a sinusoidal output voltage (no saturation). However, the output current drops to about 50mA. But the output current range is required to be from -420mA to 420mA. Is there any way to maintain this current swing without having the output voltage saturated? Thanks.

Comment: The parameters I listed worked with LTspice. Did you duplicate them? If that doesn't work perhaps you need to choose a different FET model.